# Добавить содержимое бинарного файла в объектный файл

Tags: c, массивы, файлы, линковка

Имеется программа,которая экспортирует некие данные в файл в бинарном виде.

Есть ли способ вынести содержимое константного массива, типа `uint8_t`, из си файла в отдельный бинарный файл для удобства редактирования сторонней программой?

Comment: Есть утилиты `bin2obj` например.

Comment: А что вы хотите получить в итоге? Некий бинарный файл, который будет транслироваться в `.obj`, который будет содержать массив `uint8_t`?

Comment: Можно написать кастомный скрипт для линкера.

Comment: @Dmitry Sokolov Хочу создать сторонней программой бинарный файл, и указать линковщику взять содержимое файла и связать с символом массива, т.е. определить содержимое массива в отдельном файле для удобства редактирования.

Comment: [Здесь](https://www.devever.net/~hl/incbin) перечислен, пожалуй, весь набор способов... Разве что, пропущено упоминание, что `bin2c` можно написать на коленке на любом языке...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите программу (это буквально 10 строк), которая читает бинарный файл и переводит его в текстовый .h-файл, который включается в вашу программу.

В этом тексте пишется что-то наподобие

```
unsigned char data[] = {
```

а потом идут все байты вашего бинарного файла. Если не понимаете, как это сделать - обращайтесь.

Comment: Вы правы, я так уже и сделал, но меня интересовало наличие возможности переводить сразу в obj с указанием там два символа: на сам массив и на значение размера массива. Я надеялся что есть какая нибудь директива препроцесору или линковщику.